# Having trouble in using nlinfit function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, non-linear-regression

Kindly please help me with the problem as I need to use nlinfit function for fitting unknown parameters but it is showing some error. Although yesterday I was getting some values for parameters to be fitted but now if I am running it is having some issue for the function output to be used in fitted with NaN answer for last iteration only. X data is a concatenated matrix of three columns as independent variable and yk is dependent variable, taua is a matrix of initial guesses of number of parameters to be fitted.

```
function [yk]=activity_coefficientE(taua,x)
T=523;
alpha12=0.3; alpha13=0.3; alpha21=0.3; alpha23=0.3; alpha31=0.3; alpha32=0.3;
alpha18=0.2; alpha81=0.2; alpha28=0.2; alpha82=0.2; alpha38=0.2; alpha83=0.3;
alpha19=0.2; alpha91=0.2; alpha29=0.2; alpha92=0.2; alpha39=0.2; alpha93=0.2;
alpha110=0.2;alpha101=0.2;alpha210=0.2;alpha102=0.2;alpha310=0.2;alpha103=0.2;
alpha113=0.2;alpha131=0.2;alpha213=0.2;alpha132=0.2;alpha313=0.2;alpha133=0.2;
alpha114=0.2;alpha141=0.2;alpha214=0.2;alpha142=0.2;alpha314=0.2;alpha143=0.2;
alpha115=0.2;alpha151=0.2;alpha215=0.2;alpha152=0.2;alpha315=0.2;alpha153=0.2;
alpha117=0.2;alpha171=0.2;alpha217=0.2;alpha172=0.2;alpha317=0.2;alpha173=0.2;
alpha118=0.2;alpha181=0.2;alpha218=0.2;alpha182=0.2;alpha318=0.2;alpha183=0.2;
alpha810=0.2;alpha915=0.2;alpha1314=0.2;alpha108=0.2;alpha159=0.2;alpha1413=0.2;
alpha1718=0.2;alpha1817=0.2;
tau12=0; tau13=0; tau21=0; tau23=0; tau31=0; tau32=0;
%taua=randi([-5,5],1,112)
tau18=taua(1)+taua(57)/T;
tau81=taua(2)+taua(58)/T;
tau28=taua(3)+taua(59)/T;
tau82=taua(4)+taua(60)/T;
tau38=taua(5)+taua(61)/T;
tau83=taua(6)+taua(62)/T;
tau19=taua(7)+taua(63)/T;
tau91=taua(8)+taua(64)/T;
tau29=taua(9)+taua(65)/T;
tau92=taua(10)+taua(66)/T;
tau39=taua(11)+taua(67)/T;
tau93=taua(12)+taua(68)/T;
tau110=taua(13)+taua(69)/T;
tau101=taua(14)+taua(70)/T;
tau210=taua(15)+taua(71)/T;
tau102=taua(16)+taua(72)/T;
tau310=taua(17)+taua(73)/T;
tau103=taua(18)+taua(74)/T;
tau113=taua(19)+taua(75)/T;
tau131=taua(20)+taua(76)/T;
tau213=taua(21)+taua(77)/T;
tau132=taua(22)+taua(78)/T;
tau313=taua(23)+taua(79)/T;
tau133=taua(24)+taua(80)/T;
tau114=taua(25)+taua(81)/T;
tau141=taua(26)+taua(82)/T;
tau214=taua(27)+taua(83)/T;
tau142=taua(28)+taua(84)/T;
tau314=taua(29)+taua(85)/T;
tau143=taua(30)+taua(86)/T;
tau115=taua(31)+taua(87)/T;
tau151=taua(32)+taua(88)/T;
tau215=taua(33)+taua(89)/T;
tau152=taua(34)+taua(90)/T;
tau315=taua(35)+taua(91)/T;
tau153=taua(36)+taua(92)/T;
tau117=taua(37)+taua(93)/T;
tau171=taua(38)+taua(94)/T;
tau217=taua(39)+taua(95)/T;
tau172=taua(40)+taua(96)/T;
tau317=taua(41)+taua(97)/T;
tau173=taua(42)+taua(98)/T;
tau118=taua(43)+taua(99)/T;
tau181=taua(44)+taua(100)/T;
tau218=taua(45)+taua(101)/T;
tau182=taua(46)+taua(102)/T;
tau318=taua(47)+taua(103)/T;
tau183=taua(48)+taua(104)/T;
tau810=taua(49)+taua(105)/T;
tau108=taua(50)+taua(106)/T;
tau915=taua(51)+taua(107)/T;
tau159=taua(52)+taua(108)/T;
tau1314=taua(53)+taua(109)/T;
tau1413=taua(54)+taua(110)/T;
tau1718=taua(55)+taua(111)/T;
tau1817=taua(56)+taua(112)/T;




G12=exp(-(tau12*alpha12));
G21=exp(-(tau21*alpha21));
G13=exp(-(tau13*alpha13));
G31=exp(-(tau31*alpha31));
G23=exp(-(tau23*alpha23));
G32=exp(-(tau32*alpha32));
G18=exp(-(tau18*alpha18));
G81=exp(-(tau81*alpha81));
G28=exp(-(tau28*alpha28));
G82=exp(-(tau82*alpha82));
G38=exp(-(tau38*alpha83));
G83=exp(-(tau83*alpha83));
G19=exp(-(tau19*alpha19));
G91=exp(-(tau91*alpha91));
G29=exp(-(tau29*alpha29));
G92=exp(-(tau92*alpha92));
G39=exp(-(tau39*alpha39));
G93=exp(-(tau93*alpha93));
G110=exp(-(tau110*alpha110));
G101=exp(-(tau101*alpha101));
G210=exp(-(tau210*alpha210));
G102=exp(-(tau102*alpha102));
G310=exp(-(tau310*alpha310));
G103=exp(-(tau103*alpha103));
G113=exp(-(tau113*alpha113));
G131=exp(-(tau131*alpha131));
G213=exp(-(tau213*alpha213));
G132=exp(-(tau132*alpha132));
G313=exp(-(tau313*alpha313));
G133=exp(-(tau133*alpha133));
G114=exp(-(tau114*alpha114));
G141=exp(-(tau141*alpha141));
G214=exp(-(tau214*alpha214));
G142=exp(-(tau142*alpha142));
G314=exp(-(tau314*alpha314));
G143=exp(-(tau143*alpha143));
G115=exp(-(tau115*alpha115));
G151=exp(-(tau151*alpha151));
G215=exp(-(tau215*alpha215));
G152=exp(-(tau152*alpha152));
G315=exp(-(tau315*alpha315));
G153=exp(-(tau153*alpha153));
G117=exp(-(tau117*alpha117));
G171=exp(-(tau171*alpha171));
G217=exp(-(tau217*alpha217));
G172=exp(-(tau172*alpha172));
G317=exp(-(tau317*alpha317));
G173=exp(-(tau173*alpha173));
G118=exp(-(tau118*alpha118));
G181=exp(-(tau181*alpha181));
G218=exp(-(tau218*alpha218));
G182=exp(-(tau182*alpha182));
G318=exp(-(tau318*alpha318));
G183=exp(-(tau183*alpha183));
G810=exp(-(tau810*alpha810));
G108=exp(-(tau108*alpha108));
G915=exp(-(tau915*alpha915));
G159=exp(-(tau159*alpha159));
G1314=exp(-(tau1314*alpha1314));
G1413=exp(-(tau1413*alpha1413));
G1718=exp(-(tau1718*alpha1718));
G1817=exp(-(tau1817*alpha1817));



%calculating  mole fractions of ionic species

x1=x(:,1);
x2=x(:,2);
x3=x(:,3);

%x1=[0.1577 0.1492 0.1462 0.1366 0.1299 0.1180  0.0863 0.0761 0.0550  ];
%x2=[0.8278 0.7945 0.7678 0.7450 0.6979 0.6309  0.4611 0.4114 0.2952  ];
%x3=[0.0145 0.0563 0.0860 0.1184 0.1722 0.2511  0.4526 0.5125 0.6498 ];

   
A=[0.0674243 0.0773881 0.0843400 0.0865343 0.0899223 0.0882858  0.0715087 0.0643867 0.0483658];
B=[0.0141081 0.0479814 0.0643151 0.0737477 0.0820756 0.0838701  0.0701576 0.0634457 0.0479639];
C=[0.0565665 0.0450072 0.0387724 0.0313828 0.02506094 0.0186280  0.0092734 0.0073438 0.0041595 ];
D=[0.0336447 0.0267694 0.0230611 0.0186659 0.0149058 0.0110795  0.0055157 0.0043679 0.0024739 ];
E=[0.0008148 0.0008756 0.00087131 0.0008794 0.0008711 0.0008441  0.0007384 0.0006997 0.0005980  ];
N=length(A);
x1n=zeros(N,1);x2n=zeros(N,1);x3n=zeros(N,1);
X1=zeros(N,1);X2=zeros(N,1);X3=zeros(N,1);X4=zeros(N,1);X5=zeros(N,1);X6=zeros(N,1);X7=zeros(N,1);
X12=zeros(N,1);X16=zeros(N,1);
for i=1:N
x1n(i)=(x1(i)-A(i)-D(i)-2*E(i)-C(i)+3*B(i))
x2n(i)=(x2(i)-A(i)-C(i)-D(i))
x3n(i)=(x3(i)-B(i))



X1(i)=(x1n(i)/(x1n(i)+x2n(i)+x3n(i)+2*A(i)+4*B(i)+2*C(i)+2*D(i)+2*E(i)))
X2(i)=(x2n(i)/(x1n(i)+x2n(i)+x3n(i)+2*A(i)+4*B(i)+2*C(i)+2*D(i)+2*E(i)))
X3(i)=(x3n(i)/(x1n(i)+x2n(i)+x3n(i)+2*A(i)+4*B(i)+2*C(i)+2*D(i)+2*E(i)))
X4(i)=(A(i)+D(i)+E(i)/(x1n(i)+x2n(i)+x3n(i)+2*A(i)+4*B(i)+2*C(i)+2*D(i)+2*E(i)))
X5(i)=(C(i)/(x1n(i)+x2n(i)+x3n(i)+2*A(i)+4*B(i)+2*C(i)+2*D(i)+2*E(i)))
X6(i)=(A(i)-B(i)/(x1n(i)+x2n(i)+x3n(i)+2*A(i)+4*B(i)+2*C(i)+2*D(i)+2*E(i)))
X7(i)=(B(i)/(x1n(i)+x2n(i)+x3n(i)+2*A(i)+4*B(i)+2*C(i)+2*D(i)+2*E(i)))
X12(i)=(E(i)/(x1n(i)+x2n(i)+x3n(i)+2*A(i)+4*B(i)+2*C(i)+2*D(i)+2*E(i)))
X16(i)=(C(i)+D(i)/(x1n(i)+x2n(i)+x3n(i)+2*A(i)+4*B(i)+2*C(i)+2*D(i)+2*E(i)))
end
yc4=X4./(X4+X5);
yc5=X5./(X4+X5);
yc6=X6./(X6+X7+X12+X16);
yc7=X7./(X6+X7+X12+X16);
yc12=X12./(X6+X7+X12+X16);
yc16=X16./(X6+X7+X12+X16);

alpha14=yc6.*alpha18+yc7.*alpha19+yc12.*alpha113+yc16.*alpha117;
%alpha41=alpha14;
alpha24=yc6.*alpha28+yc7.*alpha29+yc12.*alpha213+yc16.*alpha217;
%alpha42=alpha24;
alpha34=yc6.*alpha38+yc7.*alpha39+yc12.*alpha313+yc16.*alpha317;
%alpha43=alpha34;
alpha15=yc6.*alpha110+yc7.*alpha115+yc12.*alpha114+yc16.*alpha118;
%alpha51=alpha15;
alpha25=yc6.*alpha210+yc7.*alpha215+yc12.*alpha214+yc16.*alpha218;
%alpha52=alpha25;
alpha35=yc6.*alpha310+yc7.*alpha315+yc12.*alpha314+yc16.*alpha318;
%alpha53=alpha35;
alpha16=yc4.*alpha81+yc5.*alpha101;
%alpha61=alpha16;
alpha26=yc4.*alpha82+yc5.*alpha102;
%alpha62=alpha26;
alpha36=yc4.*alpha83+yc5.*alpha103;
%alpha63=alpha36;
alpha17=yc4.*alpha91+yc5.*alpha151;
%alpha71=alpha17;
alpha27=yc4.*alpha92+yc5.*alpha152;
%alpha72=alpha27;
alpha37=yc4.*alpha93+yc5.*alpha153;
%alpha73=alpha37;
alpha112=yc4.*alpha131+yc5.*alpha141;
%alpha121=alpha112;
alpha212=yc4.*alpha132+yc5.*alpha142;
%alpha122=alpha212;
alpha312=yc4.*alpha133+yc5.*alpha143;
%alpha123=alpha312;
alpha116=yc4.*alpha171+yc5.*alpha181;
%alpha161=alpha116;
alpha216=yc4.*alpha172+yc5.*alpha182;
%alpha162=alpha216;
alpha316=yc4.*alpha173+yc5.*alpha183;
%alpha163=alpha316;
alpha46=yc5.*alpha810;
%alpha64=alpha46;
alpha47=yc5.*alpha915;
%alpha74=alpha47;
alpha412=yc5.*alpha1314;
%alpha124=alpha412;
alpha416=yc5.*alpha1718;
%alpha164=alpha416;
alpha56=yc4.*alpha108;
%alpha65=alpha56;
alpha57=yc4.*alpha159;
%alpha75=alpha57;
alpha512=yc4.*alpha1413;
%alpha125=alpha512;
alpha516=yc4.*alpha1817;
%alpha165=alpha516;
G14=yc6.*G18+yc7.*G19+yc12.*G113+yc16.*G117;
%G41=G14;
G24=yc6.*G28+yc7.*G29+yc12.*G213+yc16.*G217;
%G42=G24;
G34=yc6.*G38+yc7.*G39+yc12.*G313+yc16.*G317;
%G43=G34;
G15=yc6.*G110+yc7.*G115+yc12.*G114+yc16.*G118;
%G51=G15;
G25=yc6.*G210+yc7.*G215+yc12.*G214+yc16.*G218;
%G52=G25;
G35=yc6.*G310+yc7.*G315+yc12.*G314+yc16.*G318;
%G53=G35;
G16=yc4.*G81+yc5.*G101;
%G61=G16;
G26=yc4.*G82+yc5.*G102;
%G62=G26;
G36=yc4.*G83+yc5.*G103;
%G63=G36;
G17=yc4.*G91+yc5.*G151;
%G71=G17;
G27=yc4.*G92+yc5.*G152;
%G72=G27;
G37=yc4.*G93+yc5.*G153;
%G73=G37;
G112=yc4.*G131+yc5.*G141;
%G121=G112;
G212=yc4.*G132+yc5.*G142;
%G122=G212;
G312=yc4.*G133+yc5.*G143;
%G123=G312;
G116=yc4.*G171+yc5.*G181;
%G161=G116;
G216=yc4.*G172+yc5.*G182;
%G162=G216;
G316=yc4.*G173+yc5.*G183;
%G163=G316;
G46=yc5.*G810;
%G64=G46;
G47=yc5.*G915;
%G74=G47;
G412=yc5.*G1314;
%G124=G412;
G416=yc5.*G1718;
%G164=G416;
G56=yc4.*G108;
%G65=G56;
G57=yc4.*G159;
%G75=G57;
G512=yc4.*G1413;
%G125=G512;
G516=yc4.*G1817;
%G165=G516;
tau14=-log(G14)./alpha14;
%tau41=tau14;
tau24=-log(G24)./alpha24;
%tau42=tau24;
tau34=-log(G34)./alpha34;
%tau43=tau34;
tau15=-log(G15)./alpha15;
%tau51=tau15;
tau25=-log(G25)./alpha25;
%tau52=tau25;
tau35=-log(G35)./alpha35;
%tau53=tau35;
tau16=-log(G16)./alpha16;
%tau61=tau16;
tau26=-log(G26)./alpha26;
%tau62=tau26;
tau36=-log(G36)./alpha36;
%tau63=tau36;
tau17=-log(G17)./alpha17;
%tau71=tau17;
tau27=-log(G27)./alpha27;
%tau72=tau27;
tau37=-log(G37)./alpha37;
%tau73=tau37;
tau112=-log(G112)./alpha112;
%tau121=tau112;
tau212=-log(G212)./alpha212;
%tau122=tau212;
tau312=-log(G312)./alpha312;
%tau123=tau312;
tau116=-log(G116)./alpha116;
%tau161=tau116;
tau216=-log(G216)./alpha216;
%tau162=tau216;
tau316=-log(G316)./alpha316;
%tau163=tau316;
tau46=-log(G46)./alpha46;
%tau64=tau46;
tau47=-log(G47)./alpha47;
%tau74=tau47;
tau412=-log(G412)./alpha412;
%tau124=tau412;
tau416=-log(G416)./alpha416;
%tau164=tau416;
tau56=-log(G56)./alpha56;
%tau65=tau56;
tau57=-log(G57)./alpha57;
%tau75=tau57;
tau512=-log(G512)./alpha512;
%tau125=tau512;
tau516=-log(G516)./alpha516;
%tau165=tau516;
ln_y1_1=G12.*X2.*tau12+ G31.*X3.*tau13+ G14.*X4.*tau14+G15.*X5.*tau15+G16.*X6.*tau16+G17.*X7.*tau17+G112.*X12.*tau112+G116.*X16.*tau116;
ln_y1_2=G12.*X2+ G13.*X3+ G14.*X4+G15.*X5+G16.*X6+G17.*X7+G112.*X12+G116.*X16;

ln_y2_1=G21.*X1.*tau12+ G32.*X3.*tau32+ G24.*X4.*tau24+G25.*X5.*tau25+G26.*X6.*tau26+G27.*X7.*tau27+G212.*X12.*tau212+G216.*X16.*tau216;
ln_y2_2=G12.*X1+ G23.*X3+G24.*X4+G25.*X5+G26.*X6+G27.*X7+G212.*X12+G216.*X16;

ln_y3_1=G13.*X1.*tau13+ G23.*X3.*tau23+ G34.*X4.*tau34+G35.*X5.*tau35+G36.*X6.*tau36+G37.*X7.*tau37+G312.*X12.*tau312+G316.*X16.*tau316;
ln_y3_2=G13.*X1+ G23.*X3+ G34.*X4+G35.*X5+G36.*X6+G37.*X7+G312.*X12+G316.*X16;

ln_y4_1=G14.*X1.*tau14+G24.*X2.*tau24+G34.*X3.*tau34+G46.*X6.*tau46+G47.*X7.*tau47+G412.*X12.*tau412+G416.*X16.*tau416;
ln_y4_2=G14.*X1+G24.*X2+G34.*X3+G46.*X6+G47.*X7+G412.*X12+G416.*X16;

ln_y5_1=G15.*X1.*tau15+G25.*X2.*tau25+G35.*X3.*tau35+G56.*X6.*tau56+G57.*X7.*tau57+G512.*X12.*tau512+G516.*X16.*tau516;
ln_y5_2=G15.*X1+G25.*X2+G35.*X3+G56.*X6+G57.*X7+G512.*X12+G516.*X16;

ln_y6_1=G16.*X1.*tau16+G26.*X2.*tau26+G36.*X3.*tau36+G46.*X4.*tau46+G56.*X5.*tau56;
ln_y6_2=G16.*X1+G26.*X2+G36.*X3+G46.*X4+G56.*X5;

ln_y7_1=G17.*X1.*tau17+G27.*X2.*tau27+G37.*X3.*tau37+G47.*X4.*tau47+G57.*X5.*tau57;
ln_y7_2=G17.*X1+G27.*X2+G37.*X3+G47.*X4+G57.*X5;

ln_y12_1=G112.*X1.*tau112+G212.*X2.*tau212+G312.*X3.*tau312+G412.*X4.*tau412+G512.*X5.*tau512;
ln_y12_2=G112.*X1+G212.*X2+G312.*X3+G412.*X4+G512.*X5;

ln_y16_1=G116.*X1.*tau116+G216.*X2.*tau216+G316.*X3.*tau316+G416.*X4.*tau416+G516.*X5.*tau516;
ln_y16_2=G116.*X1+G216.*X2+G316.*X3+G416.*X4+G516.*X5;

ln_y1_3=(((X2.*G12)./ln_y2_2).*(tau12-(ln_y2_1)./(ln_y2_2)))+(((X3.*G13)./ln_y3_2).*(tau13-(ln_y3_1)./(ln_y3_2)));
ln_y1_4=(((X6.*G16)./ln_y6_2).*(tau16- (ln_y6_1./ln_y6_2))) + (((X7.*G17)./ln_y7_2).*(tau17- (ln_y7_1./ln_y7_2)))+(((X12.*G12)./ln_y12_2).*(tau112- (ln_y12_1./ln_y12_2)))+(((X16.*G16)./ln_y16_2).*(tau116- (ln_y16_1./ln_y16_2)));
ln_y1_5=(((X4.*G14)./ln_y4_2).*(tau14- (ln_y4_1./ln_y4_2))) + (((X5.*G15)./ln_y5_2).*(tau15- (ln_y5_1./ln_y5_2)));

yk=exp((ln_y1_1./ln_y1_2) + ln_y1_3 + ln_y1_4+ ln_y1_5)   % activity coefficient for H2O

end

........................................
Another function where above function to be called.....

    
% calling the function act_coeff to estimate the binary interaction parameters
for i=1:112   
filename = 'EagelsDATA.xlsx';  %reading VLE data from excel file

Data = xlsread(filename);
x(:,1) = Data([10:15 17:19],16);
x(:,2) = Data([10:15 17:19],1);
x(:,3)= Data([10:15 17:19],2);
taua=(randi([-5,5],1,112));
 
yk=[0.0606                   (values calculated from above function and  will be used for fitting)
    0.4327
    0.6545
    0.9417
    1.2570
    1.6881
    1.9108
    1.7777
    1.3821]
 

% taua =[   -2     3     4    -3    -4     1     4    -2     4    -4    -1     4     5    -3     3     2    -5     3    -4

   %  1     4     1     5    -1    -1    -3     2    -3     4     3     4     2     5     4    -2     4     3    -1

    % 1     0    -5    -5    -5    -3     4     2     1     4     0     2    -3    -4     5     0    -3     2     5

    % 1     0     5     1    -3     5     4     1     5     2     3     2     0    -5    -4    -2     1    -2     5

    %-5     5    -2    -2     4     1    -1     3    -1     1     5    -1     0    -1     4     5     5     1     4

    % 1     0     4    -4     4     0    -1    -2    -5    -3    -4    -5
    % -5     0    -2     0    -5]            (random values for which yk was calculted from the command 
                                                      taua= randi([-5,5],1,112))


try     % try-catch used to continue the loop without stopping on encountering an error
[taua1]= nlinfit(x,yk,@activity_coefficientE,taua)
catch exception
    continue
end
end


 

I am not able to attach excel sheet here so data from excel sheet is as:

x =[0.1577 0.1492 0.1462 0.1366 0.1299 0.1180  0.0863 0.0761 0.0550;  column 1
     0.8278 0.7945 0.7678 0.7450 0.6979 0.6309  0.4611 0.4114 0.2952 ; column 2
     0.0145 0.0563 0.0860 0.1184 0.1722 0.2511  0.4526 0.5125 0.6498 ]; column 3
```

Comment: Is this in Matlab or Excel?

Comment: It is MATLAB , where data from excel sheet was used

Comment: So, not an Excel problem then, and you don't want an answer in Excel either. Then remove the Excel tag.

Answer (score 0):

I found 3 major problems with what you did.

**Problem #1 - errors**
The reason you get the error is because your function "activity_coefficientE" can sometimes return NaN or inf values.  My suggestion is to look for these values and set the value of "yk" to a large value so that the optimizer in "nlinfit" will stay away from coefficients that produce infinite or NaN values.  This is the code at the bottom of the function so that you avoid crashes:

```
if any(~isfinite(yk))
   yk = 10 * ones(size(yk));
end
```

**Problem #2 - random initial guesses**
The trouble with using random numbers for your initial conditions is that every time you run it you get a different answer, so sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.  If you set the random number generator seed, you can get the same random numbers each time you run the script.  If you change you seed, you can get a different set of random numbers.  I shortened your main script to this, where I try 100 different random seeds (and store the results of each attempt) to see what answers result:

```
for i=1:100  
   rng(i)
   taua = randi([-5,5],1,112);
   taua1(i, :) = nlinfit(x,yk,@activity_coefficientE,taua);
end
```

Each row of "taua1" is a set of 111 coefficients.

**Problem #3 - Trying to fit 9 points with 112 coefficients**
Every time nlinfit is called, you get this warning:

Warning: Rank deficient

because you have more coefficients (112) that you are asking nlinfit to find than data points you are fitting (9).  It's like trying to find the 2nd order equation that best fits 2 points, there are an infinite number of solutions.  When curve fitting you should have more data points than coefficients to make sure you're not fitting noise.  You need more data points in "yk" and "x" and/or fewer coefficients to fit.  I've done a lot of curve fitting and I've never seen an equation with 112 coefficients, so I am thinking that you are not solving the problem correctly.  Perhaps the 112 coefficients aren't really independent or there are 112 data points and 9 coefficients that you want to find.

For completeness, here is my edited version of the activity_coefficientE.m function that I created to work on this solution.  In general, I never see Matlab code with this many variables with similar names.  Much of this code could be greatly simplified by using vector operations.  Most of my changes involve formatting, adding semicolons, and the checks for non-finite values at the end.

```
function yk=activity_coefficientE(taua,x)
T=523;
alpha12=0.3; alpha13=0.3; alpha21=0.3; alpha23=0.3; alpha31=0.3; alpha32=0.3;
alpha18=0.2; alpha81=0.2; alpha28=0.2; alpha82=0.2; alpha38=0.2; alpha83=0.3;
alpha19=0.2; alpha91=0.2; alpha29=0.2; alpha92=0.2; alpha39=0.2; alpha93=0.2;
alpha110=0.2;alpha101=0.2;alpha210=0.2;alpha102=0.2;alpha310=0.2;alpha103=0.2;
alpha113=0.2;alpha131=0.2;alpha213=0.2;alpha132=0.2;alpha313=0.2;alpha133=0.2;
alpha114=0.2;alpha141=0.2;alpha214=0.2;alpha142=0.2;alpha314=0.2;alpha143=0.2;
alpha115=0.2;alpha151=0.2;alpha215=0.2;alpha152=0.2;alpha315=0.2;alpha153=0.2;
alpha117=0.2;alpha171=0.2;alpha217=0.2;alpha172=0.2;alpha317=0.2;alpha173=0.2;
alpha118=0.2;alpha181=0.2;alpha218=0.2;alpha182=0.2;alpha318=0.2;alpha183=0.2;
alpha810=0.2;alpha915=0.2;alpha1314=0.2;alpha108=0.2;alpha159=0.2;alpha1413=0.2;
alpha1718=0.2;alpha1817=0.2;
tau12=0; tau13=0; tau21=0; tau23=0; tau31=0; tau32=0;
tau18=taua(1)+taua(57)/T;
tau81=taua(2)+taua(58)/T;
tau28=taua(3)+taua(59)/T;
tau82=taua(4)+taua(60)/T;
tau38=taua(5)+taua(61)/T;
tau83=taua(6)+taua(62)/T;
tau19=taua(7)+taua(63)/T;
tau91=taua(8)+taua(64)/T;
tau29=taua(9)+taua(65)/T;
tau92=taua(10)+taua(66)/T;
tau39=taua(11)+taua(67)/T;
tau93=taua(12)+taua(68)/T;
tau110=taua(13)+taua(69)/T;
tau101=taua(14)+taua(70)/T;
tau210=taua(15)+taua(71)/T;
tau102=taua(16)+taua(72)/T;
tau310=taua(17)+taua(73)/T;
tau103=taua(18)+taua(74)/T;
tau113=taua(19)+taua(75)/T;
tau131=taua(20)+taua(76)/T;
tau213=taua(21)+taua(77)/T;
tau132=taua(22)+taua(78)/T;
tau313=taua(23)+taua(79)/T;
tau133=taua(24)+taua(80)/T;
tau114=taua(25)+taua(81)/T;
tau141=taua(26)+taua(82)/T;
tau214=taua(27)+taua(83)/T;
tau142=taua(28)+taua(84)/T;
tau314=taua(29)+taua(85)/T;
tau143=taua(30)+taua(86)/T;
tau115=taua(31)+taua(87)/T;
tau151=taua(32)+taua(88)/T;
tau215=taua(33)+taua(89)/T;
tau152=taua(34)+taua(90)/T;
tau315=taua(35)+taua(91)/T;
tau153=taua(36)+taua(92)/T;
tau117=taua(37)+taua(93)/T;
tau171=taua(38)+taua(94)/T;
tau217=taua(39)+taua(95)/T;
tau172=taua(40)+taua(96)/T;
tau317=taua(41)+taua(97)/T;
tau173=taua(42)+taua(98)/T;
tau118=taua(43)+taua(99)/T;
tau181=taua(44)+taua(100)/T;
tau218=taua(45)+taua(101)/T;
tau182=taua(46)+taua(102)/T;
tau318=taua(47)+taua(103)/T;
tau183=taua(48)+taua(104)/T;
tau810=taua(49)+taua(105)/T;
tau108=taua(50)+taua(106)/T;
tau915=taua(51)+taua(107)/T;
tau159=taua(52)+taua(108)/T;
tau1314=taua(53)+taua(109)/T;
tau1413=taua(54)+taua(110)/T;
tau1718=taua(55)+taua(111)/T;
tau1817=taua(56)+taua(112)/T;

G12=exp(-(tau12*alpha12));
G21=exp(-(tau21*alpha21));
G13=exp(-(tau13*alpha13));
G31=exp(-(tau31*alpha31));
G23=exp(-(tau23*alpha23));
G32=exp(-(tau32*alpha32));
G18=exp(-(tau18*alpha18));
G81=exp(-(tau81*alpha81));
G28=exp(-(tau28*alpha28));
G82=exp(-(tau82*alpha82));
G38=exp(-(tau38*alpha83));
G83=exp(-(tau83*alpha83));
G19=exp(-(tau19*alpha19));
G91=exp(-(tau91*alpha91));
G29=exp(-(tau29*alpha29));
G92=exp(-(tau92*alpha92));
G39=exp(-(tau39*alpha39));
G93=exp(-(tau93*alpha93));
G110=exp(-(tau110*alpha110));
G101=exp(-(tau101*alpha101));
G210=exp(-(tau210*alpha210));
G102=exp(-(tau102*alpha102));
G310=exp(-(tau310*alpha310));
G103=exp(-(tau103*alpha103));
G113=exp(-(tau113*alpha113));
G131=exp(-(tau131*alpha131));
G213=exp(-(tau213*alpha213));
G132=exp(-(tau132*alpha132));
G313=exp(-(tau313*alpha313));
G133=exp(-(tau133*alpha133));
G114=exp(-(tau114*alpha114));
G141=exp(-(tau141*alpha141));
G214=exp(-(tau214*alpha214));
G142=exp(-(tau142*alpha142));
G314=exp(-(tau314*alpha314));
G143=exp(-(tau143*alpha143));
G115=exp(-(tau115*alpha115));
G151=exp(-(tau151*alpha151));
G215=exp(-(tau215*alpha215));
G152=exp(-(tau152*alpha152));
G315=exp(-(tau315*alpha315));
G153=exp(-(tau153*alpha153));
G117=exp(-(tau117*alpha117));
G171=exp(-(tau171*alpha171));
G217=exp(-(tau217*alpha217));
G172=exp(-(tau172*alpha172));
G317=exp(-(tau317*alpha317));
G173=exp(-(tau173*alpha173));
G118=exp(-(tau118*alpha118));
G181=exp(-(tau181*alpha181));
G218=exp(-(tau218*alpha218));
G182=exp(-(tau182*alpha182));
G318=exp(-(tau318*alpha318));
G183=exp(-(tau183*alpha183));
G810=exp(-(tau810*alpha810));
G108=exp(-(tau108*alpha108));
G915=exp(-(tau915*alpha915));
G159=exp(-(tau159*alpha159));
G1314=exp(-(tau1314*alpha1314));
G1413=exp(-(tau1413*alpha1413));
G1718=exp(-(tau1718*alpha1718));
G1817=exp(-(tau1817*alpha1817));



%calculating  mole fractions of ionic species

x1=x(:,1);
x2=x(:,2);
x3=x(:,3);

   
A=[0.0674243 0.0773881 0.0843400 0.0865343 0.0899223 0.0882858  0.0715087 0.0643867 0.0483658];
B=[0.0141081 0.0479814 0.0643151 0.0737477 0.0820756 0.0838701  0.0701576 0.0634457 0.0479639];
C=[0.0565665 0.0450072 0.0387724 0.0313828 0.02506094 0.0186280  0.0092734 0.0073438 0.0041595 ];
D=[0.0336447 0.0267694 0.0230611 0.0186659 0.0149058 0.0110795  0.0055157 0.0043679 0.0024739 ];
E=[0.0008148 0.0008756 0.00087131 0.0008794 0.0008711 0.0008441  0.0007384 0.0006997 0.0005980  ];
N=length(A);
x1n=zeros(N,1);x2n=zeros(N,1);x3n=zeros(N,1);
X1=zeros(N,1);X2=zeros(N,1);X3=zeros(N,1);X4=zeros(N,1);X5=zeros(N,1);X6=zeros(N,1);X7=zeros(N,1);
X12=zeros(N,1);X16=zeros(N,1);
for i=1:N
   x1n(i)=(x1(i)-A(i)-D(i)-2*E(i)-C(i)+3*B(i));
   x2n(i)=(x2(i)-A(i)-C(i)-D(i));
   x3n(i)=(x3(i)-B(i));

   X1(i)=(x1n(i)/(x1n(i)+x2n(i)+x3n(i)+2*A(i)+4*B(i)+2*C(i)+2*D(i)+2*E(i)));
   X2(i)=(x2n(i)/(x1n(i)+x2n(i)+x3n(i)+2*A(i)+4*B(i)+2*C(i)+2*D(i)+2*E(i)));
   X3(i)=(x3n(i)/(x1n(i)+x2n(i)+x3n(i)+2*A(i)+4*B(i)+2*C(i)+2*D(i)+2*E(i)));
   X4(i)=(A(i)+D(i)+E(i)/(x1n(i)+x2n(i)+x3n(i)+2*A(i)+4*B(i)+2*C(i)+2*D(i)+2*E(i)));
   X5(i)=(C(i)/(x1n(i)+x2n(i)+x3n(i)+2*A(i)+4*B(i)+2*C(i)+2*D(i)+2*E(i)));
   X6(i)=(A(i)-B(i)/(x1n(i)+x2n(i)+x3n(i)+2*A(i)+4*B(i)+2*C(i)+2*D(i)+2*E(i)));
   X7(i)=(B(i)/(x1n(i)+x2n(i)+x3n(i)+2*A(i)+4*B(i)+2*C(i)+2*D(i)+2*E(i)));
   X12(i)=(E(i)/(x1n(i)+x2n(i)+x3n(i)+2*A(i)+4*B(i)+2*C(i)+2*D(i)+2*E(i)));
   X16(i)=(C(i)+D(i)/(x1n(i)+x2n(i)+x3n(i)+2*A(i)+4*B(i)+2*C(i)+2*D(i)+2*E(i)));
end
yc4=X4./(X4+X5);
yc5=X5./(X4+X5);
yc6=X6./(X6+X7+X12+X16);
yc7=X7./(X6+X7+X12+X16);
yc12=X12./(X6+X7+X12+X16);
yc16=X16./(X6+X7+X12+X16);

alpha14=yc6.*alpha18+yc7.*alpha19+yc12.*alpha113+yc16.*alpha117;
alpha24=yc6.*alpha28+yc7.*alpha29+yc12.*alpha213+yc16.*alpha217;
alpha34=yc6.*alpha38+yc7.*alpha39+yc12.*alpha313+yc16.*alpha317;
alpha15=yc6.*alpha110+yc7.*alpha115+yc12.*alpha114+yc16.*alpha118;
alpha25=yc6.*alpha210+yc7.*alpha215+yc12.*alpha214+yc16.*alpha218;
alpha35=yc6.*alpha310+yc7.*alpha315+yc12.*alpha314+yc16.*alpha318;
alpha16=yc4.*alpha81+yc5.*alpha101;
alpha26=yc4.*alpha82+yc5.*alpha102;
alpha36=yc4.*alpha83+yc5.*alpha103;
alpha17=yc4.*alpha91+yc5.*alpha151;
alpha27=yc4.*alpha92+yc5.*alpha152;
alpha37=yc4.*alpha93+yc5.*alpha153;
alpha112=yc4.*alpha131+yc5.*alpha141;
alpha212=yc4.*alpha132+yc5.*alpha142;
alpha312=yc4.*alpha133+yc5.*alpha143;
alpha116=yc4.*alpha171+yc5.*alpha181;
alpha216=yc4.*alpha172+yc5.*alpha182;
alpha316=yc4.*alpha173+yc5.*alpha183;
alpha46=yc5.*alpha810;
alpha47=yc5.*alpha915;
alpha412=yc5.*alpha1314;
alpha416=yc5.*alpha1718;
alpha56=yc4.*alpha108;
alpha57=yc4.*alpha159;
alpha512=yc4.*alpha1413;
alpha516=yc4.*alpha1817;
G14=yc6.*G18+yc7.*G19+yc12.*G113+yc16.*G117;
G24=yc6.*G28+yc7.*G29+yc12.*G213+yc16.*G217;
G34=yc6.*G38+yc7.*G39+yc12.*G313+yc16.*G317;
G15=yc6.*G110+yc7.*G115+yc12.*G114+yc16.*G118;
G25=yc6.*G210+yc7.*G215+yc12.*G214+yc16.*G218;
G35=yc6.*G310+yc7.*G315+yc12.*G314+yc16.*G318;
G16=yc4.*G81+yc5.*G101;
G26=yc4.*G82+yc5.*G102;
G36=yc4.*G83+yc5.*G103;
G17=yc4.*G91+yc5.*G151;
G27=yc4.*G92+yc5.*G152;
G37=yc4.*G93+yc5.*G153;
G112=yc4.*G131+yc5.*G141;
G212=yc4.*G132+yc5.*G142;
G312=yc4.*G133+yc5.*G143;
G116=yc4.*G171+yc5.*G181;
G216=yc4.*G172+yc5.*G182;
G316=yc4.*G173+yc5.*G183;
G46=yc5.*G810;
G47=yc5.*G915;
G412=yc5.*G1314;
G416=yc5.*G1718;
G56=yc4.*G108;
G57=yc4.*G159;
G512=yc4.*G1413;
G516=yc4.*G1817;
tau14=-log(G14)./alpha14;
tau24=-log(G24)./alpha24;
tau34=-log(G34)./alpha34;
tau15=-log(G15)./alpha15;
tau25=-log(G25)./alpha25;
tau35=-log(G35)./alpha35;
tau16=-log(G16)./alpha16;
tau26=-log(G26)./alpha26;
tau36=-log(G36)./alpha36;
tau17=-log(G17)./alpha17;
tau27=-log(G27)./alpha27;
tau37=-log(G37)./alpha37;
tau112=-log(G112)./alpha112;
tau212=-log(G212)./alpha212;
tau312=-log(G312)./alpha312;
tau116=-log(G116)./alpha116;
tau216=-log(G216)./alpha216;
tau316=-log(G316)./alpha316;
tau46=-log(G46)./alpha46;
tau47=-log(G47)./alpha47;
tau412=-log(G412)./alpha412;
tau416=-log(G416)./alpha416;
tau56=-log(G56)./alpha56;
tau57=-log(G57)./alpha57;
tau512=-log(G512)./alpha512;
tau516=-log(G516)./alpha516;
ln_y1_1=G12.*X2.*tau12+ G31.*X3.*tau13+ G14.*X4.*tau14+G15.*X5.*tau15+G16.*X6.*tau16+G17.*X7.*tau17+G112.*X12.*tau112+G116.*X16.*tau116;
ln_y1_2=G12.*X2+ G13.*X3+ G14.*X4+G15.*X5+G16.*X6+G17.*X7+G112.*X12+G116.*X16;

ln_y2_1=G21.*X1.*tau12+ G32.*X3.*tau32+ G24.*X4.*tau24+G25.*X5.*tau25+G26.*X6.*tau26+G27.*X7.*tau27+G212.*X12.*tau212+G216.*X16.*tau216;
ln_y2_2=G12.*X1+ G23.*X3+G24.*X4+G25.*X5+G26.*X6+G27.*X7+G212.*X12+G216.*X16;

ln_y3_1=G13.*X1.*tau13+ G23.*X3.*tau23+ G34.*X4.*tau34+G35.*X5.*tau35+G36.*X6.*tau36+G37.*X7.*tau37+G312.*X12.*tau312+G316.*X16.*tau316;
ln_y3_2=G13.*X1+ G23.*X3+ G34.*X4+G35.*X5+G36.*X6+G37.*X7+G312.*X12+G316.*X16;

ln_y4_1=G14.*X1.*tau14+G24.*X2.*tau24+G34.*X3.*tau34+G46.*X6.*tau46+G47.*X7.*tau47+G412.*X12.*tau412+G416.*X16.*tau416;
ln_y4_2=G14.*X1+G24.*X2+G34.*X3+G46.*X6+G47.*X7+G412.*X12+G416.*X16;

ln_y5_1=G15.*X1.*tau15+G25.*X2.*tau25+G35.*X3.*tau35+G56.*X6.*tau56+G57.*X7.*tau57+G512.*X12.*tau512+G516.*X16.*tau516;
ln_y5_2=G15.*X1+G25.*X2+G35.*X3+G56.*X6+G57.*X7+G512.*X12+G516.*X16;

ln_y6_1=G16.*X1.*tau16+G26.*X2.*tau26+G36.*X3.*tau36+G46.*X4.*tau46+G56.*X5.*tau56;
ln_y6_2=G16.*X1+G26.*X2+G36.*X3+G46.*X4+G56.*X5;

ln_y7_1=G17.*X1.*tau17+G27.*X2.*tau27+G37.*X3.*tau37+G47.*X4.*tau47+G57.*X5.*tau57;
ln_y7_2=G17.*X1+G27.*X2+G37.*X3+G47.*X4+G57.*X5;

ln_y12_1=G112.*X1.*tau112+G212.*X2.*tau212+G312.*X3.*tau312+G412.*X4.*tau412+G512.*X5.*tau512;
ln_y12_2=G112.*X1+G212.*X2+G312.*X3+G412.*X4+G512.*X5;

ln_y16_1=G116.*X1.*tau116+G216.*X2.*tau216+G316.*X3.*tau316+G416.*X4.*tau416+G516.*X5.*tau516;
ln_y16_2=G116.*X1+G216.*X2+G316.*X3+G416.*X4+G516.*X5;

ln_y1_3=(((X2.*G12)./ln_y2_2).*(tau12-(ln_y2_1)./(ln_y2_2)))+(((X3.*G13)./ln_y3_2).*(tau13-(ln_y3_1)./(ln_y3_2)));
ln_y1_4=(((X6.*G16)./ln_y6_2).*(tau16- (ln_y6_1./ln_y6_2))) + (((X7.*G17)./ln_y7_2).*(tau17- (ln_y7_1./ln_y7_2)))+(((X12.*G12)./ln_y12_2).*(tau112- (ln_y12_1./ln_y12_2)))+(((X16.*G16)./ln_y16_2).*(tau116- (ln_y16_1./ln_y16_2)));
ln_y1_5=(((X4.*G14)./ln_y4_2).*(tau14- (ln_y4_1./ln_y4_2))) + (((X5.*G15)./ln_y5_2).*(tau15- (ln_y5_1./ln_y5_2)));

yk=exp((ln_y1_1./ln_y1_2) + ln_y1_3 + ln_y1_4+ ln_y1_5)';   % activity coefficient for H2O

if any(~isfinite(yk))
   yk = 10 * ones(size(yk));
end
```